# sed and its segmentation fault after compilation

Tags: linux, segmentation-fault, symlink

I am using an open source code **susp3d.** In this code there is a file named **sed.c** after compiling it I got a continuous **segmentation fault(core dumped)** message twice immediately aster each log in session, even when I log in as substitute user or su.
Here is one of the core dump message I retrieve using : `file core.2979`

```
core.2979: ELF 32-bit LSB core file Intel 80386, version 1 (SYSV), SVR4-style, from 'sed -n /^COLOR.*none/Ip'
```

I am not quite sure but I guess that it might be linked to a dynamic linking problem as I try to make a soft-link with `ln -sf` and compile it with the utility, make.

Here we have the steps I went through to find the error:

mussie@localhost:/home/mussie[6:55pm]#cd LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D/data_src/

```
`box*  box.c  coord*  coord.c  den_prof*  den_prof.c  header.h  makefile  msg_ser.o  prof*`  prof.c  README.txt  sed*  sed.c  utils.o
```

mussie@localhost:/home/mussie/LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D/data_src[6:55pm]#gdb s

```
sed*   sed.c
```

mussie@localhost:/home/mussie/LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D/data_src[6:55pm]#gdb sed

```
  GNU gdb (GDB) Fedora (7.4.50.20120120-54.fc17)
    Copyright (C) 2012 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
    License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
    This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
    There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
    and "show warranty" for details.
    This GDB was configured as "i686-redhat-linux-gnu".
    For bug reporting instructions, please see:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
    Reading symbols from /home/mussie/LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D-3.6.1/data_src/sed...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
```

(gdb) run

```
Starting program: /home/mussie/LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D-3.6.1/data_src/sed

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4302c60f in __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=nptr@entry=0x0,   endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x431a78a0) at strtol_l.c:298
298   while (ISSPACE (*s))
```

(gdb) backtrace

```
#0  0x4302c60f in __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=nptr@entry=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x431a78a0) at strtol_l.c:298

#1  0x4302c3c0 in __GI_strtol (nptr=0x0, endptr=0x0, base=10) at strtol.c:110

#2  0x08048723 in main ()
```

(gdb) frame 2

```
#2  0x08048723 in main ()
```

(gdb) frame 0

```
    #0  0x4302c60f in __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=nptr@entry=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x431a78a0) at strtol_l.c:298

298   while (ISSPACE (*s))
```

(gdb) print s

```
$1 = 0x0
```

(gdb) print ISSPACE

```
No symbol "ISSPACE" in current context.
```

(gdb) print s

```
$2 = 0x0
```

(gdb) break strtol_l.c:298

```
Breakpoint 1 at 0x4302c601: strtol_l.c:298. (8 locations)
```

(gdb) kill

Kill the program being debugged? (y or n) y

(gdb) break strtol_l.c:298

```
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x43093e4b.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4309374b.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x430932e3.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x43092e23.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4302d85d.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4302d09d.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4302cb71.
Note: breakpoint 1 also set at pc 0x4302c601.
```

Breakpoint 2 at 0x43093e4b: strtol_l.c:298. (8 locations)

(gdb) run

Starting program: /home/mussie/LatticeBoltzmann/Susp3D-3.6.1/data_src/sed

```
Breakpoint 1, __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=nptr@entry=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x431a78a0) at strtol_l.c:298
298   while (ISSPACE (*s))
(gdb) print s
$3 = 0x0
```

(gdb) print s

```
   $4 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $5 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $6 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $7 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $8 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $9 = 0x0
    (gdb) print s
    $10 = 0x0
    (gdb) next

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x4302c60f in __GI_____strtol_l_internal (nptr=nptr@entry=0x0, endptr=endptr@entry=0x0, base=base@entry=10, group=group@entry=0, loc=0x431a78a0) at strtol_l.c:298
298   while (ISSPACE (*s))
```